# Android Java: Update a TextView every x seconds without user input

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app in Android Java, using Android Studio.
Every 0.1 seconds I want to update the text within a certain TextView.

I already managed to use a Handler to execute a method every 0.1 seconds (100 ms), but it doesn't automatically update the TextView.

It only updates the TextView to what I want when the user interacts with the app. It only updates it when, for example, the user slides the SeekBar or presses a button. It doesn't update when the user clicks on the screen, and not automatically without input either.

How can I make it such that it will update the value automatically, without user input?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I'm new to Android and Java, and I'm using threads to get the value, in xml format, from a website.

Should I post any code, and if so, what exactly?

Comment: yes put your code here for more understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try updating the value of text view on the UI thread.

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //update TextView here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to put the code you wrote inside the Runnable of the Handler? So here, inside the method 'public void run() {.. here ..}' of the Runnable? I tried this and it showed the same, but I could be wrong

Comment: yes. write it were you are calling the method after every 0.1 sec

Comment: Thank you, it works nicely now! But where could I actually have found this information about runOnUiThread()? How could I have known about it if I didn't ask a question (for possible future problems). Because I couldn't seem to find it on the Android documentation website. Thanks!

Comment: the changes you are making in the UI without any user input needs to be done on the UIthread only. although you need to do minimal tasks on the UI thread as it can make your application slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // update TextView here!
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    t.start();
```

You can update your textview using thread also, like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int prStatus = 0;
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (prStatus < 100) {
                prStatus += 1;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(prStatus + "/");
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(150);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(prStatus == 100)
                    prStatus = 0;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```